# Fix "Waiting until last debugger command completes" in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, debugging

My project in My Android Studio. Version of my android studio "Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2"
When i try debug, affter end progress, android studio show for me "Waiting until last debugger command completes" then my application waiting before crash.

Possible workarounds that can't solve my problem:

1. Disable "Enable alternative Throwable object's stack trace"
2. Disable " Enable 'toString()' object view"